# C# string storage for white-space

Tags: c#, string, list, storage, whitespace

I'm asking if there's a difference between the following two strings:

```
string s1 = "Hello World";
string s2 = "Hello" + " " + "World";
```

because "Hello" + " " + "World" is working for me with List functions like .Any() .Contains() and .Equals() whereas "Hello World" doesn't work for these functions here.

Comment: Yes the second is a concatenation of 3 strings, but that shouldn't have an impact on the resulting string and `Any`, `Contains` & `Equals` should work on both. There must be something wrong with the way you're trying to use these Linq methods.

Comment: show the code that doesn't do what you expect to better illustrate your description.

Comment: I store strings in an application file "Autodesk Revit" and when I store these data back and compare it, only the concatenated string works with what's retrieved if it's the same way I store strings with.

Comment: Your second line is identical to the first, as the compiler performs the concatenation. How exactly are you "storing", "retrieving" and "comparing" the strings?

Comment: Unfortunately the code will not help because it's running over Revit API layer so perhaps this is a Revit API problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using them in the same file?
It's possible that you haven't included `using System.Linq` in the problematic place.

Comment: Since these are all string literals concatenation happens at compile time so they are identical.

Comment: A basic explanation is that the space is not actually the space you expected.  Unicode provides several flavors of it, the next likely one is U+00A0, a non-breaking space.  Copy/pasting the string from a web site is a common cause of such trouble.  Use s1.ToCharArray() in the watch expression to see actual character codes, also reveals any non-printing codepoints.

Answer (score 3):

the simple answer is that there is no difference!

The IEnumerable extension methods (also called LINQ for objects) you mentioned (.Any() etc.)  work on both strings as `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

example:

```
string s1 = "Hello World";
string s2 = "Hello" + " " + "World";

Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(s1.Select(s => s.ToString())));
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(s2.Select(s => s.ToString())));
```

output:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

try it:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/BKTMHj